# JWPlayer : Video is not open in full view with Chrome version 71 in ANDROID

Tags: android, android-studio, jwplayer

Jwplayer full-screen view is not working from full-screen toggle button and Screen rotation in Android. It was working fine Previously.

It was not working with latest Chrome App version 71.

How we can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**me has solved dis issue. If any issue regarding jwplayer version 
  please write here**

Update JWPlayer dependency 
app Gradle

**implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:3.4.1'
  implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:3.4.1'**

When you will update Jwplayer version some override method param needs to be the change

if you want to upgrade version **2.X to 3.X** tan you TEMPhas to upgrade your JwPlayer **licence key** also and need **3.X** licence key